# Redirect 301 /subfolder/old-page-name.html http://domain.com/new-page-name.html Not Working

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm a complete novice but don't see what I'm doing wrong with what would appear to be very simple page by page redirects for pages that have changed names but have identical content.

This is the .htaccess file with just one of the page redirects below the canonical redirect:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{http_host} ^clarityperformancealliance.com [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.clarityperformancealliance.com/$1 [r=301,nc]

Redirect 301 /clarity/[A].html http://www.clarityperformancealliance.com/current-performance.html
```

I realize that the old page is a *very* poorly named page (using brackets) but I don't think the brackets are why it's failing because I've tried to redirect pages that have more normal names without brackets and they fail as well.

I'm on a shared Network Solutions Linux server using what I assume is an Apache server.  They have their shared servers set up in what I assume is pretty typical fashion in that my root folder is called htdocs and I can create as many subfolders and websites within them as I want to, thus I have a subfolder named "clarity" for this particular website.

The non-www to www redirect works perfectly.  It's all the individual page redirects (only one shown here) that aren't working.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Redirect is using %-encoded url, so I think the `[A].html` should be `%5BA%5D.html`

Now your configuration seems right, except if the clarity subfolder is the website root, in this case the url path argument in Redirect should not contain the `/clarity` part; Redirect works on the request uri, not on the filesystem path.

So it's maybe:

```
Redirect 302 /%5BA%5D.html http://www.clarityperformancealliance.com/current-performance.html
```

Note that I have used a **302** and not a 301. Until the rule is working you should always work with 302 (temporary) redirects and not 301 (permanent). When working with permanent redirects you need to close your web browser between each modification if you want to test it. The browser is not re-asking for a given url after he received a 301.

If this is not working, do you experiment redirection problems only with old url in the old domain or also when requesting theses old url on the new domain?